# Libgdx forcing Garbage Collector

Tags: java, android, libgdx

My game is composed of Main Menu (25 objects -> it is a dynamic menu, everything is moving), Game Over (3 objects), Game Screen(15 - 20 objects), Game Shop (40 objects)... So my game has used about 50mb of ram and then steadly increased, because well I am creating so many objects!

But of course I just used the command System.gc() in my Main Menu and now it is always at about 25mb, and there seem to be no problems! But people say it is bad practice to to that.

But the screens get destroyed, and I don't want to keep the objects that would waste my RAM, so it seems like this is the only solution!

Comment: Are you correctly calling ```dispose``` on things like shaperenderers? Otherwise the native objects attached to them never get cleaned up.

Comment: Well umm, each of my objects in game shop for example has a sprite and a rectangle class... And those don't have a disposable method... The textures I am loading from my asset manager!

Comment: You should reuse every object being created in your game loop and sparingly create new objects. You are creating a pointer to a new location in memory (and filling the memory) every time you create a new object, where most of your new objects created could probably just use a field update or two.

Comment: Well yeah, the game loop I know... But the thing is my Game Shop for example has 40 objects, which get created once the screen is created and destroyed once the screen has changed... So I cannot really just allocate once + if I destroy the objects I am using less memory.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you use the libgdx way of memory management, make sure that you dispose all objects that implements disposable, you can find a list of disposable objects **[here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management)**, also you can use object Pooling which is a common pattern for memory management used in libgdx :

regards to libgdx wiki :

> Object pooling is the principle of reusing inactive or "dead" objects,
>   instead of creating new objects every time. This is achieved by
>   creating an object pool, and when you need a new object, you obtain it
>   from that pool. If the pool has an available (free) object, it is
>   returned. If the pool is empty, or does not contain free objects, a
>   new instance of the object is created and returned. When you no longer
>   need an object, you "free" it, which means it is returned to the pool.
>   This way, object allocation memory is reused, and garbage collector is
>   happy.

**[Object pooling](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management#object-pooling)**

Comment: Isn't object pooling for the Game Screen, where objects are like spawning and have a short life period? Here I am destroying the screens... And the objects in Game Shop once they are created they never get destroyed until screen get's destroyed. Unless I make it static, but well they say it is not good to go with it!

Comment: you can use object pooling for your Game shop instead of explicitly invoking sys.gc

Comment: Well, so I would create the objects in the started class, which runs the program and make the objects there already, and the pass them around? Seems a little messy... + each of those objects has a texture and its using quite some ram

Comment: try it and then you can judge if it's messy or not